# how to get pixel color using byte array in Android

Tags: android, performance, byte, getpixel

In my Android project,
Here is my code.

```
for (int x = 0; x < targetBitArray.length; x += weight) {
    for (int y = 0; y < targetBitArray[x].length; y += weight) {
        targetBitArray[x][y] = bmp.getPixel(x, y) == mSearchColor;
    }
}
```

but this code wastes a lot of time.

So I need to find way faster than bitmap.getPixel().
I'm trying to get pixel color using byte array converted from bitmap, but I can't.
How to replace Bitmap.getPixel()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Bitmap.getPixel method invocation requires a lot of resources, so you need to avoid the amount of requests in order to improve the performace of your code.

My suggestion is:

1. Read the image data row-by-row with Bitmap.getPixels method into a local array
2. Iterate along your local array

e.g.

```
int [] rowData= new int [bitmapWidth];
for (int row = 0; row < bitmapHeight; row ++) {
    // Load row of pixels
    bitmap.getPixels(rowData, 0, bitmapWidth, 0, row, bitmapWidth, 1);

    for (int column = 0; column < bitmapWidth; column ++) {
        targetBitArray[column][row] = rowData(column) == mSearchColor;
    }
}
```

This will be a great improvement for the performace of your code